# Chrome extension is not installed again through registry if it was deleted

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have extension in chrome store. 
At first I added programmatically chrome extension through registry. 
Next I removed by hands this extension in Chrome. And added programmatically folder in registry again. But it didn't install in browser. 
Also when I removed extension, the folder with extension_id in registry didn't remove, so it even didn't change when I install it again... 
How can I solve it? (without solution through chrome store "Add plugin")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intentional. If the user decides to delete an automatically installed extension, it is **blacklisted** on that profile and will not be installed automatically again. There's nothing you can (automatically) do.

From [the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions):

> ### What if the user uninstalls the extension?
>
> If the user uninstalls the extension through the UI, it will no longer be installed or updated on each startup. In other words, the external extension is blacklisted.

A user, however, can clear the blacklist by going to the Web Store and installing from there:

> ### How do I get off the blacklist?
>
> If the user uninstalls your extension, you should respect that decision. However, if you (the developer) accidentally uninstalled your extension through the UI, you can remove the blacklist tag by installing the extension normally through the UI, and then uninstalling it.